# @Cacheable with null key

Tags: java, spring, caching, key, memcached

I have a service that uses `@Cacheable` to cache the results of a method

```
getRestaurants(Boolean closed)

@Override
@Cacheable(value = "defaultCache", key = "#root.methodName.concat('-').concat(#closed")
public List<Restaurant> getRestaurants(Boolean closed) {
```

This method can be called with closed = null in order to return all restaurants.  This results in a null pointer exception.

How do we add a condition to the key to allow for null values?

Comment: may the using the save navigation operator could work, see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-operator-safe-navigation

Answer (score 0):

You could not allow null values in the cached method and make a second method `getAllRestaurants`. Both could internally still dispatch to your existing code.